# Load Model From Layout

Tags: codeigniter

I have a layout located at

```
/addons/default/themes/base_theme/views/layouts/jobs
```

which I access through the url

```
/jobs
```

I would like to be able to use some queries I just wrote for a module in this layout without re-coding them.

However, I can't seem to load the model file inside my layout.

How do you load a model file inside a layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a way to import models into codeigniter layout files.

The solution was to create a custom module with the same name and refactor the existing code into it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not load models inside views.

You should send the data from the controllers and check in the layout to see if the data you are looking for was sent or not.

Comment: Do you know what controller is tied to files in the /layout folder & can you differentiate between which layout is trying to be loaded? I don't want to be pulling back stuff from the database unnecessarily.

Comment: If you are using that layout only from Jobs controller, then send the variables only from Jobs controller to the view.

Comment: And where would this jobs controller be? There isn't a controller folder with this base_theme, the layout files look to be setup used somewhere in the code (haven't found it yet). Are you familiar with codeigniter?